# QML 'Custom Menu' option moving upwards

Tags: qt, animation, menu, qml

I am trying to create a "menu" in QML with custom data in each option
For requirements of my application, I need to show it loading the QML file dynamically (`Qt.createComponent`). What I need is to show some fixed options in the bottom part, and when clicked the top one, another options appear below this top option, which keeps in the top
A simple example. I have this menu:

```
Option 4
Option 2
Option 1
```

And when clicked in `Option 4`, the menu changes to

```
Option 4
Option 3
Option 2
Option 1
```

So `Option 4` is moved upwards and `Option 3` appears.

I would like to have a 'shadow' around all my menu (I added a `DropShadow` component for that purpose).

I have this simple test code, where I have a main `Rectangle` (to be surrounded by the shadow), and 2 Rectangles inside. 
`Rect1` for the fixed part (`Option 1`, `Option 2`), and `Rect2` for the 'movable' part (`Option 3`, `Option 4`).
`Rect2` is behind `Rect1` (`z: -1`), and located to have only `Option 4` visible, above `Option 2`. When clicked `Option 4`, `Rect2` is moved upwards and all options are visible.

To achieve that, I have to update `Rect2` visible height, and main window position (`y` value), since main window height depends on this `Rect2` visible height.

I have it working, but it flicks a lot since 2 variables changes ('fixed panel' is moved upwards and back).

I have also tried with a `ParallelAnimation` for 2 values, but no success.

Any idea to have this menu with a smooth movement?

**`Main.qml`:**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle 
{
    id: window

    property variant win: undefined;
    Component.onCompleted: 
   {
        var component = Qt.createComponent("TestMenu.qml");
        win = component.createObject(window, {"x": 500, "y": 500});
        win.show();
    }
}
```

**`TestMenu.qml:`**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Window {
    id: window
    flags: Qt.Tool | Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    height: panel.height
    color: "transparent"

    property int radiusShadow: 20
    property int iOptionHeight: 30

    Rectangle {
        id: panel
        anchors { centerIn: parent}

        height: menu1.height + menu2.heightVisible + 2*radiusShadow
        width: window.width - 2*radiusShadow
        color: "transparent"

        Rectangle {
            id: menu1

            anchors { bottom: parent.bottom; bottomMargin: radiusShadow }
            width: parent.width
            height: column1.children.length * iOptionHeight

            Column {
                id: column1
                anchors.fill: parent
                Rectangle {
                    color: "red";
                    Text { text: qsTr("option 2") }
                    height: iOptionHeight;  width: parent.width
                }
                Rectangle {
                    color: "green";
                    Text { text: qsTr("option 1") }

                    height: iOptionHeight;  width: parent.width
                }
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: menu2

            property int heightVisible: iOptionHeight

            anchors { top: parent.top; topMargin: radiusShadow; left: menu1.left }
            width: parent.width
            height: column2.children.length * iOptionHeight

            z: -1

            Column {
                id: column2

                anchors.fill: parent
                Rectangle {
                    id: blue
                    property bool bOpen: false
                    color: "blue";
                    height: iOptionHeight;  width: parent.width
                    Text { text: qsTr("option 4") }

                    MouseArea {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        onClicked: {
                            blue.bOpen = !blue.bOpen;
                            panel.showHideMenu2(blue.bOpen);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Rectangle {
                    color: "pink";
                    Text { text: qsTr("option 3") }
                    height: iOptionHeight;  width: parent.width
                }
            }
        }

        function showHideMenu2(bShow)
        {
            if (bShow)
            {
                window.y -= iOptionHeight
                menu2.heightVisible += iOptionHeight;
            }
            else
            {
                window.y += iOptionHeight
                menu2.heightVisible -= iOptionHeight;
            }
        }
    }

    DropShadow {
        id: dropShadow
        visible: true
        anchors.fill: panel
        radius: radiusShadow
        samples: 24
        color: "#40000000"
        source: panel
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick answer for your question, you can get what you want using [`Behavior`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-behavior.html) animation for a property change.

Here, `Behavior` animation will be used on `y` (position) change of your `window`, and for `height` change of respective rectangles.

Here is the patch for your code I recommend you to apply to see smooth movement:

```
@@ -10,6 +10,9 @@

     property int radiusShadow: 20
     property int iOptionHeight: 30
+    property int animationDuration: 500 // ms
+
+    Behavior on y { NumberAnimation { duration: window.animationDuration } }

     Rectangle {
         id: panel
@@ -18,6 +21,7 @@
         height: menu1.height + menu2.heightVisible + 2*radiusShadow
         width: window.width - 2*radiusShadow
         color: "transparent"
+        Behavior on height { NumberAnimation { duration: window.animationDuration } }

         Rectangle {
             id: menu1
@@ -25,6 +29,7 @@
             anchors { bottom: parent.bottom; bottomMargin: radiusShadow }
             width: parent.width
             height: column1.children.length * iOptionHeight
+            Behavior on height { NumberAnimation { duration: window.animationDuration } }

             Column {
                 id: column1
@@ -52,6 +57,8 @@
             width: parent.width
             height: column2.children.length * iOptionHeight

+            Behavior on height { NumberAnimation { duration: window.animationDuration } }
+
             z: -1

             Column {
@@ -64,6 +71,7 @@
                     color: "blue";
                     height: iOptionHeight;  width: parent.width
                     Text { text: qsTr("option 4") }
+                    Behavior on height { NumberAnimation { duration: window.animationDuration } }

                     MouseArea {
                         anchors.fill: parent
@@ -77,6 +85,7 @@
                     color: "pink";
                     Text { text: qsTr("option 3") }
                     height: iOptionHeight;  width: parent.width
+                    Behavior on height { NumberAnimation { duration: window.animationDuration } }
                 }
             }
         }
@@ -105,4 +114,4 @@
         color: "#40000000"
         source: panel
     }
-}+}
```

Comment: Really thanks for your help, but adding these Behavior's does not fix my problem. When clicking in Option 4, all options move a little, the effect is really bad... :(

Comment: It is your error in calculations, but not with smooth movement. Be more specific when you are trying to describe your problem.

Comment: Sorry If I didn't explain my problem properly... What error do you mean? I can not find what is wrong. Thanks a lot

Comment: Diego, please, try to describe precisely what do you want to get (add picture/video if required). And it seems like it will be need queastion, since this one about smooth movement is already answered.

Comment: I will try to explain what I want: I want menu2 go up (to see Option 3 and Option 4), so main window must increase its height (and also moves up to avoid that by default it increases its height donwards). Menu1 should stay at the bottom of the window while these changes. 

Maybe the code I use is not the best way to achieve it. With the Behaviour's my menu2 goes up with smooth movement, but menu1 flickers. Maybe some calculation is not correct, but it is not very complex and I can not find where is the problem. Thanks for being patient

Comment: Diego, you are lucky one, here is quick re-implementation of your code -- https://github.com/troyane/StackOverflow-pro/tree/master/so_smooth hope it will be good base for you.

But for the next time asking on StackOverflow you should specialize your question as more as possible + reduce your question to [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise you'll get no answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot troyane. I have tried the code but (altough it is really simpler than mine) it does not work like expected. The 2 bottom options should stay at the bottom, but they moves (uggly effect) while main window height is increased... I though I had posted a working code as simple as I could, sorry if it was not like that...

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with a model and a ListView (code is simpler now), but I don't know where and how insert an 'Animation' or a 'Behaviour' to achieve my target, if it is possible to do it (I have tried several options with no success...)

The expected effect is that the 1st rectangle moves up when the 2nd appears, so the bottom one keeps in its position (at bottom). But the default behaviour when I add an element to the model is that the list increased the height downwards

Maybe anyone could help...

My code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Rectangle {
    id: rootItem
    width: 400
    height: list.height

    ListModel {
        id: modelRects
        ListElement {  rectColor: "green" }
        ListElement {  rectColor: "orange" }
    }

    ListView {
        id: list
        height: modelRects.count * 30
        model: modelRects
        delegate: Rectangle {
                id: delegate
                height: 30
                width: rootItem.width
                color: rectColor

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: onRectClicked(index);
                }
            }
        }

    function onRectClicked(index)
    {
        if (index == 0)
        {
            if (modelRects.count == 2)
                modelRects.insert(1, {"idRect": 2, "rectColor": "red"});
            else
                modelRects.remove(1, 1);
        }
    }
}
```